# PHP Connection_Aborted() Works Only Sometimes

Tags: php, apache, apache2, download

I have file download PHP script. The script can download large files up to 4GB+. In reality, it will often happen that users will cancel download process or will close browser window while downloading.

I have to, therefore, register when the already started download process will have been for any reason aborted. The optimal solution for this looks to be monitoring connection via [connection_aborted()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.connection-aborted.php) function.

'connection_aborted()' seems to react on download cancel or closing my browser window. My problem is, that it does not react with 100% precision. It registers about 50% of cancelled downloads or closed browsers. If the connection abort is not detected, the download simply continues on the server as if the browser would not cancel it.

Would you, please, review my code for vulnerabilities and errors? I need to understand, what causes the behavior:

```
// empty and turn off output buffering
    ob_flush();
    flush();


    // never expire this download script
    set_time_limit(0);

    fseek($fileObject, $seek_start);

    while(!feof($fileObject))
    {
        //usleep(100000);

        //print(@fread($fileObject, $chunkSize));
        echo(@fread($fileObject, $chunkSize));

        // gradually output buffer to avoid memory problems by downloading large files
        ob_flush();
        flush();

        // check if the client was disconnected
        // important for cancelled or interrupted downloads
        if (Connection_Aborted())
        {
            ChromePhp::log("Connection Aborted");

            // sent to the database that the connection has been aborted
            $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "UPDATE current_downloads SET connection_aborted=TRUE WHERE user_id=1;");

            // close the database connection
            mysqli_close($dbc);

            // close the open file
            @fclose($fileObject);

            exit(json_encode(array("result" => false, "error" => "Connection with the client was aborted.")));
        }

        $nLoopCounter++;
        $transferred += $chunkSize;
        $downloadPercentage = (($nLoopCounter * $chunkSize) / $fileSize) * 100;

        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "UPDATE current_downloads SET progress_percent=$downloadPercentage, transferred=$transferred, connection_aborted=$strConnectionAborted, iteration=$nLoopCounter WHERE user_id=1;");
        if($result == false)
        {
            // close the database connection
            mysqli_close($dbc);

            // close the file
            fclose($handle);

            // prepare output message
            $outputArray = array("result" => 0, "message" => "Error Processing Database Query");

            // output the message
            echo json_encode($outputArray);
            exit;
        }
    }

    // file save was a success
    @fclose($fileObject);
```

*I use the following:*

- Apache 2.4.4
- PHP 5.4.12
- MySQL 5.6.12
- Google Chrome Version 32.0.1700.107 m
- Windows 7 x64

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the function `connection_status`,and then try again

```
if(connection_status()!=0||connection_aborted()!=0||){
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Hi Xiongji, thanks for the response. I have tested the modified `if( (connection_status()!=0) || (connection_aborted()!=0) )` but unfortunately no change. Error logs showed no errors neither.