# Alternative to PHP Function connection_aborted()?

Tags: php, websocket

I spent already over two days on this problem. It looks that PHP function connection_aborted() does not work reliably. Sometimes it reports aborted connection with the client properly, but in about 50% it does not report the abort.

Is there any other way to detect aborted connection with the client from within the PHP script, please? Maybe establishing socket connection or anything else?

### Sample code:

*This is my latest version of the file downloading code. Downloading works properly even on large files, but `connection_aborted()` works only occasionally.*

```
// disable script abort
ignore_user_abort(true);

// never expire this download script
set_time_limit(0);

 while(!feof($fileObject) && (connection_status()==0))
        {
            //usleep(100000);

            print(@fread($fileObject, $chunkSize));

            // gradually output buffer to avoid memory problems by downloading large files
            ob_flush();
            flush();

            $nLoopCounter++;
            $transferred += $chunkSize;
            $downloadPercentage = (($nLoopCounter * $chunkSize) / $fileSize) * 100;

            $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "UPDATE current_downloads SET progress_percent=$downloadPercentage, transferred=$transferred, connection_aborted=$strConnectionAborted, iteration=$nLoopCounter WHERE user_id=1;");
            if($result == false)
            {
                // close the database connection
                mysqli_close($dbc);

                // close the file
                fclose($handle);

                // prepare output message
                exit(json_encode(array("result" => false, "error" => "Error Processing Database Query.")));
            }
        }

        // check if the client was disconnected
        // important for cancelled or interrupted downloads
        if ( (connection_status()!=0) || (connection_aborted()!=0) )
        {
            // empty the output buffer
            ob_flush();
            flush();

            ChromePhp::log("Connection Aborted");

            // sent to the database that the connection has been aborted
            $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "UPDATE current_downloads SET connection_aborted=TRUE WHERE user_id=1;");

            // close the database connection
            mysqli_close($dbc);

            // close the open file
            @fclose($fileObject);

            exit(json_encode(array("result" => false, "error" => "Connection with the client was aborted.")));
        }
```

Thank you and kind regards.

Comment: I miss `ignore_user_abort()` in the code. Note that the error message "Connection with the client was aborted" is meaningless, as the connection was aborted.

Comment: Have you read this? http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.connection-status.php#43273

Comment: The script is actually much longer, and `ignore_user_abort(true)` is at the top of the script. I will update the sample code, so it is obvious, it has not been forgotten.

Comment: ok. have you read the comments I've sent? looks like connection_aborted is more fragile than I thought

Comment: Oh yes, I have read that link too. And I am sending output to the client on every iteration, just see the line with `print(@fread($fileObject, $chunkSize));`

Comment: Yes buddy, I have read all your comments and clicked on every one. There are many posts claiming issues with `connection_aborted()`. I tent to believe, that there is issue with the Apache or PHP server. I tried multiple clients too. They all behave the same, sometimes `connection_aborted()` works well, but often it does not, without any change in the script.

Comment: what about this? http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.connection-aborted.php#111167

Comment: That one talks about sending 0 to the output buffer/client. I have tried the same but via `chr(0)` PHP function. However, that should not be necessary, because, I output data to the output buffer on every iteration, as the script saves the file.

Comment: yeah, normally this shouldn't be are problem here, but what counts "normally" ;)

Comment: I am trying it again to send `echo("0");`. I have even tried to completely turn off output buffer in php.ini. However, then my downloads completely freeze.

Comment: how should the `connection_close()` getting reached? (Check your current `while` condition)

Comment: I am not sure, if I have your question correctly. I do not call `connection_close()` anywhere in my script. Regarding my `while()` condition, it will exit if the connection is aborted. Then the script continues and reaches processing the MySQL query.

Comment: sorry meant `connection_abort()`.. its late here.. cu tomorrow

Comment: Yes, I assumed that was small mistake. I am trying to upgrade PHP on my machine. Have a good night.

Answer (score 0):

With default settings PHP will just abort the running script if the browser closes the connection. You can change this default behaviour using the function `ignore_user_abort()` or the ini setting `ignore_user_abort`.

In order to use the function `connection_aborted()` you need to do one of those steps before because otherwise `connection_aborted()` will never reached. Here comes an example with `ignore_user_abort()`:

```
ignore_user_abort(TRUE);
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    sleep(1);
    // click the stop button in your browser ...
    if(connection_aborted()) {
        // we can't use echo anymore as the connection to the
        // browser was closed. that's why we write to test file
        file_put_contents('/tmp/test.file', 'The connection was aborted');
    }
}
```

But that's not all. If you register a shutdown function using `register_shutdown_function()` this function will get called even if the scripts has been told to terminate because of missing `ignore_user_abort()`. The following example shows this:

```
register_shutdown_function(function() {
    // click the stop button in your browser ...
    if(connection_aborted()) {
        // we can't use echo anymore as the connection to the
        // browser was closed. that's why we write to test file
        file_put_contents('/tmp/test.file', 'The connection was aborted');
    }
});
```

You can follow this article in the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php. It explains PHP's connection handling.

Comment: hi and thanks for your response. I know `ignore_user_abort()`. Actually, `true` parameter needs to be sent to this function to ignore script abort. Despite I have set this funciton to `true` I am still having issues. Therefore, I have asked for alternatives.

Comment: Oh, missed the `true`. Follow the manual page I've linked. It should explain everything

Comment: Are you talking about a websocket server or a php script running by a web server?

Comment: I think, I have tried everything that was possible to try with `connection_aborted()`. I have read over 60 posts discussing `connection_aborted()`, but for me it still does not work stable. Sometimes it reports connection abort properly, but in about 50% it ignores the fact, that the connection was aborted. I thought, that possibly establishing websocket connection with the client, or any other way could provide alternative to `connection_aborted()`. Websocket connection was just an example, as I do not really know, if there is any substitute for `connection_aborted()`.

Comment: how do you simulate the connection abort? are you sure that the script hasn't finished before you close the connection? ensure this using `connection_status()`

Comment: please, take a look at [this other question, I have asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813862/php-connection-aborted-works-only-sometimes). You can find there the script, I used to get file download abort. I am sure that the script does not get aborted, because the MySQL database gets continuously update, despite cancelling the download. But remember, sometimes it works properly but sometimes it does not.

Comment: I have the server installed on my computer. It is Windows 7 x64 with WAMP Server running on it.

Comment: this answer has absolutely nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @AlexandreMartini Feel free to give a better answer if you think that.