# Stop PHP script from executing if client disconnects

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, https, connection

I'm having the following problem.

Client from program sends an HTTPS action to server. Server gets the action and all params that are required. But then client disconnects while PHP script that is called is working.

The script echos back the response and the client doesn't get anything like it shouldn't. Because it is important action and client should always get the response I want to stop PHP script from executing if this scenario ever happens.

The entire script is in MySQL transaction so if it dies db rollback will occur and it's essential that it does.

I have put this code at the very end of script

```
ob_end_clean();

header("Connection: close");

ignore_user_abort();

ob_start();

echo $response->asXML();

$size = ob_get_length();

header("Content-Length: $size");

ob_end_flush();

flush();

if ( connection_aborted() )
        log('Connection aborted');
else
        log('Connection is fine');
```

But connection_aborted always returns 0 (NORMAL CONNECTION) so the script always executes.
`connection_status` also doesn't help, so I don't know what else to try.

EDIT:

I figured it out that this never works only when the script is called with an AJAX request. When it is called with regular HTTP it shows that connection is dead. But when I call it with `new XMLHttpRequest()` it never figures it out that connection is closed.

It asynchronous request.

So I managed to narrow it down. But I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php#111167

Comment: @IssamZoli It still does't work. After I put ob_flush() and flush() before connection_aborted() I get 0 as an output. I also echo response before flush, that doesn't help me neither.

Comment: try `if (connection_aborted())` instead of `if (connection_aborted()==1)`

Comment: @IssamZoli I'm already doing that if (connection_aborted() )

Comment: Try this http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-status.php#43273

Comment: @IssamZoli I'm already echoing xml data to the client before i check for connection, I'm also using flush and ob_flush still no progress.

Comment: If this is crytical part of your project and PHP is not giving you the result you want, I suggest switching to an asynchronous technology like Node.js to get real-time connection status

Answer (score 5):

After some experimentation, it seems you need to do multiple flushes (writes) to the connection to have PHP detect that the connection has aborted. However it seems you want to write your output as one big chunk of XML data. We can get around the problem of having no more data to send by using the `chunked` transfer encoding for HTTP requests.

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ignore_user_abort(true);

while (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_end_clean();
}

header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
header('Transfer-Encoding: chunked');
header('Connection: close');

// ----- Do your MySQL processing here. -----

// Sleep so there's some time to abort the connection. Obviously this wouldn't be
// here in production code, but is here to simulate time to process the request.
sleep(3);

// Put XML content into $xml. If output buffering is used, dump contents to $xml.
//$xml = $response->asXML();
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><test/>';
$size = strlen($xml);

// If connection is aborted before here, connection_status() will not return 0.

echo dechex($size), "\r\n", $xml, "\r\n"; // Write content chunk.

echo "0\r\n\r\n"; // Write closing chunk, detecting if connection closed.

if (0 !== connection_status()) {
    error_log('Connection aborted.');
    // Rollback MySQL transaction.
} else {
    error_log('Connection successful.');
    // Commit MySQL transaction.
}
```

`ob_implicit_flush(true)` tells PHP to make a flush after each `echo` statement. The connection status is checked after each chunk is sent with `echo`. If the connection is closed before the first statement, `connection_status()` should return a non-zero value.

You may need to use `ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0)` at the top of the script to turn off output compression if compression is turned on in php.ini, otherwise it acts as another external buffer and `connection_status()` may always return `0`.

---

EDIT: The `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header modifies the way the browser expects to receive data in the HTTP response. The browser then expects to receive data in as chunks with the form `[{Hexadecimal number of bytes in chunk}\r\n{data}\r\n]`. So for example, you can send the string "This is an example string." as a chunk by echoing `1a\r\nThis is an example string.\r\n`. The browser would only display the string, not `1a`, and keep the connection open waiting until it receives an empty chunk, that is, `0\r\n\r\n`.

---

EDIT: I modified the code in my answer so that it works as a standalone script, rather than rely on `$response` being defined by the OP's code. That is, I commented the line with `$xml = $response->asXML();` and replaced it with `$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><test/>';` as a proof of concept.

Comment: Hi thanks for your replay. I'm having problems with echoing dechex($size) and 0 because it corrupts xml data, so the client reports an error and it can't read data properly.

Comment: To see what I wrote actually work, copy and paste the code from my answer into an empty PHP script, and replace `$xml = $response->asXML();` with `$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><test/>';`. Drop that in for your real script, and it should do what you're wanting.

Comment: I had put the header header('Transfer-Encoding: chunked'); but like i said i have string "c6" that dechex($size) generates, new line at the start is also a problem because xml is not at start of entity.

Comment: It is possible you need to also add `ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);` to the top of your script, as this will buffer output and could be interfering with the `Transfer-Encoding` header. It is also possible that some other code you're using could be setting the `Transfer-Encoding` header, possibly whatever generates the `$response` object. Could you show me what the actual headers are that are being served. Also, could you try using the exact code from my answer to see if that works (if it doesn't, also try adding `ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you must not rely on connection_aborted() function: there are some user reports (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23530884/3908097, [Alternative to PHP Function connection_aborted()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21815886/3908097)) that it is not reliable. Also consider situations when network timeout occurs.

I suggest another idea, which by my opinion is more reliable. It's simple: send XML data to the client and then wait some time for
acknowledge: client sends another HTTP request with confirmation when the data was obtained.
After this confirmation you can commit transaction. In case of timeout - rollback.

This idea requires just minor modifications to server's php and client's code.

Modified your php code (test1.php):

```
ob_end_clean();
header("Connection: close");
ignore_user_abort(true);
ob_start();

echo $response->asXML();

$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");

// *** added lines ***
$serial = rand();
$memcache_obj = memcache_connect('localhost', 11211);
$memcache_obj->set("test1.$serial", 0);
header("X-test1-serial: $serial");
// ***

ob_end_flush();
flush();

// *** changed code ***
$ok = 0;
$tmout = 10*1000; // timeout in milliseconds
// wait until confirmation flag changes to 1 or timeout occurs
while (!($ok = intval($memcache_obj->get("test1.$serial"))))
{
    if (connection_aborted()) break; // then no wait
    if (($tmout = $tmout - 10) <= 0) break;
    usleep(10000); // wait 10 milliseconds
}
$memcache_obj->delete("test1.$serial");

if ($ok) {
   error_log('User informed');
   // commit transaction
} else {
   error_log('Timeout');
   // rollback transaction
}
```

Code which handles client confirmation (user_ack.php):

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
$serial = intval($_GET['serial']);

$memcache_obj = memcache_connect('localhost', 11211);
$memcache_obj->replace("test1.$serial", 1);
echo $serial;
```

And finally client's code (test1.html) to test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Test connection</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function user_ack(serial) {
    var httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpReq.open("GET", "user_ack.php?serial=" + encodeURIComponent(serial), true);
    httpReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (httpReq.readyState == 4) {
            if (httpReq.status == 200) {
                // confirmation successful
                document.getElementById("ack").textContent = httpReq.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    httpReq.send("");
}

function get_xml() {
    var httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpReq.open("POST", "test1.php", true);
    httpReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (httpReq.readyState == 4) {
            if (httpReq.status == 200) {
                // send confirmation
                var serial = httpReq.getResponseHeader("X-test1-serial");
                user_ack(serial);

                // ... process XML ...
                document.getElementById("xml").textContent = httpReq.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    httpReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpReq.send("id=abc"); // parameters to test1.php
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>XML from server:</p>
<div id="xml"></div>

<p>Confirmation serial: <span id="ack"></span></p>
<p><input type="button" value="XML download test" onclick="get_xml();"/></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I use memcached to store value of confirmation flag for communication between test1.php and user_ack.php. This value's name must by unique for each connection, so I use `$serial = rand();` to generate name: `"test1.$serial"`. When created confirmation flag has value 0. After confirmation `user_ack.php` changes it value to 1.

Because `user_ack.php` must known flag's value name, client sends confirmation with $serial value. Value of $serial it gets form server in the custom HTTP header: `X-test1-serial` when gets XML.

I use memcache for simplicity. Also MySQL table can by used for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

PHP can detect the connection is aborted only when it tries to send some output to browser. Try to output some whitespace characters, `flush()` output, then test `connection_status()`. You might have to output enough characters to get the buffer through, in my case 64 kb worked.

```
ob_end_flush();
flush();
sleep(10);
ignore_user_abort(true);
echo str_repeat(' ', 1024*64);
flush();

if ( connection_status() != 0 )
    die();
```

Notice I added `ignore_user_abort(true)`, without it, the execution will end at script output, that is at `echo` or `flush()`.

Comment: It still does't work. After I put ob_flush() and flush() before connection_status and connection_aborted() I get 0 as an output of both functions. I also echo response before flush, that doesn't help me neither.

Comment: Apache might have its own buffer on. I just tested experimentaly, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I use lighttpd not apache but i will test this also and let you know

Comment: Have you tried to increase the output from 64kb to more?